# How to get latest SQL Server version when creating Azure SQL database

Tags: sql-server, azure

I believed that I always got the latest version of SQL Server when creating a new Azure database from the Azure Portal. But that is not happening.

I always get sql Server version (12.0.2000.8) which is SQL 2014. I can't find other places to set a new compability level either.

Is there a problem with my subscription (pay as you go)??

Have any of you had the same experience as me, have you been able to solve it?

The reason I want SQL 2017 is that I want to publish SSIS packages to the SSISDB catalog, which is not possible on SQL 2014?

Hope any of you can help me out here

regards GEir

Comment: SSISDB (specifically the SSIS Project Deployment method) was introduced in SQL Server 2012. It is available in SQL Server 2014.

Comment: [Microsoft's FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-faq) confirms V12 is the current version in Azure. [This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lift-shift/ssis-azure-deploy-run-monitor-tutorial?view=sql-server-2017) claims you do need version 17.2 or later of SQL Server Management Studio; I see no similar requirement for the server instance. So you may be good to go.

Comment: There is no problem with your version or with publishing packages to SSISDB. What is specifically stopping you creating an SSISDB right now using the normal methods? Keep in mind that to use an SSISDB in SQL Azure, it probably makes sense to use Azure Data Factory v2 which hosts and executes packages in the cloud.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use SSIS on DB engine 12 on Azure. Check out official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-deploy-ssis-packages-azure).

Additionally, you may upgrade your already-created azure databases by setting COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL modificator. Look into ALTER_TABLE documentation for [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-2017).

Please note that although SQL Azure's engine share similar "engine api" as SQL Server 2014  (v12), those are not the same. What's more relevant in terms of supported features is maximum supported "[Compatibility level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-2017)".